# create menu without nav-view in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to create one auto hide menu, without using `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` element.

I don't want to use

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/home-root.html',
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'HomeController'
    });
```

Please some give me the sample code for this

Comment: please be more specific and your Question is not appropriate and please try  to stick to the point what you want to convey and try to complete the sentence

Comment: you can use `<ion-modal-view></ion-modal-view>`